# Two jQuery toggles not working

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

Can anyone please tell me why this stupid code isn't working on my site? Am I crazy, or is there a conflict?

```
<div class="row faqbody question">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <button class="question">
                    <h5>
                        Do I get to pick which chef makes my pie?
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
                    </h5>
                </button>                             
            </div>
        </div>                
        <div class="row answer">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>Nope....</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.question').click( function() {
    console.log('Question Clicked');    

    if ($(this).find('.fa').hasClass('fa-caret-up')) {
        console.log('Has Fa-caret-up');
        $(this).find('.fa').removeClass('fa-caret-up');
        $(this).find('.fa').addClass('fa-caret-down');  
    }

    if ($(this).find('.fa').hasClass('fa-caret-down')) {
        console.log('Has Fa-caret-down');
        $(this).find('.fa').removeClass('fa-caret-down');
        $(this).find('.fa').addClass('fa-caret-up');    
    }   

    $(this).parent('div').parent('div').next('.answer').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

The answer shows no problem, and the reason the caret is coded in such a funky way is because the below does not work:

```
$( this ).find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
```

I've never seen this before. Normally simple stuff like this isn't a problem.

Thank you in advance, I'm hoping this is a simple one!

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: working on my site, create jsfiddle it;s better to showcase

Comment: I don't see a caret to toggle in your HTML - but the 'Nope' toggles just fine if that is what you were trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding your click listener to `.question`. You have a button with that class inside a div with that class.  Your event is dispatching twice (once from each object), so the toggle is negated. You can see it in the console - all your log entries are doubled.

See the snippet below, the fix is basically just be more explicit with your selector:

**Change:**

```
$('.question').click(...);
```

**To:**

```
$('button.question').click(...)
```

*PS... This snippet runs without FontAwesome, so I just added an `X` in your `<i>` tag and some styles so you could see that it changes and the classes are assigned correctly.*

```js
$('button.question').click( function() {
    console.log('Question Clicked');    
    $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-caret-up').toggleClass('fa-caret-down'); 
    $(this).parent('div').parent('div').next('.answer').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
i.fa.fa-caret-up {
  color: red;
  }

i.fa.fa-caret-down {
  color: blue;
  }

.hidden {
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row faqbody question">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <button class="question"><h5>Do I get to pick which chef makes my pie? <i class="fa fa-caret-up">X</i></h5></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row answer hidden">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p>Nope....</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```